# How do I count the number of duplicates for each countries using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My following code is able to count the number of distinct cities.

**Get distinct countries**

```
    IpDetails.find().distinct('city', function(error, cities) {
    console.log(`unique cities is:, ${cities}`)
})
```

**Results**

```
unique cities is: Toronto, Waterloo
```

My question is, how do I get the number of times that Toronto and Waterloo appeared in my database using mongoose? Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [$aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). Effectively you would group each object by the the value of `city` and increment the count for each:

```
IpDetails.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$city", count: { $sum: 1 } } }],
  function(error, groups) {
    groups.forEach(function(group) {
      console.log(`City ${group._id} appeared ${group.count} times`);
    });
  }
);
```

Hopefully that helps!